# How can I emulate register_globals in PHP 5.4 or newer?

Tags: php, register-globals

I am working on a framework that uses `register_globals`. My local php version is 5.4.

I know `register_globals` is deprecated since PHP 5.3.0 and removed in PHP 5.4, but I have to make this code work on PHP 5.4.

Is there any way to emulate the functionality on newer versions of PHP?

Comment: PHP Manual says `This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.` Hence i'm afraid there is no easy way around it

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ : Yeah mate, i know that. I can't understand why these frameworks still uses register_globals :@. Any way thanks for the comment Mate.

Comment: You could switch to a newer version of the framework that does not require register_globals, or to a completely different framework.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can emulate `register_globals` by using [extract](http://php.net/extract) in global [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

```
extract($_REQUEST);
```

Or put it to independent function using global and [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
function globaling()
{
    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $val)
    {
        global ${$key};
        ${$key} = $val;
    }
}
```

If you have a released application and do not want to change anything in it, you can create `globals.php` file with

```
<?php
extract($_REQUEST);
```

then add [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive to .htaccess (or in php.ini)

```
php_value auto_prepend_file ./globals.php
```

After this the code will be run on every call, and the application will work as though the old setting was in effect.

Comment: Can you please reference a page in the PHP manual or elsewhere describing that function or language construct?

Comment: Thanks @sectus, i will try with the independent function.

Comment: I hadn't seen `extract()` often enough to think of it for this issue, but that's perfect. You can even be a little more selective by doing `extract($_GET)` or `extract($_POST)`. I was also thinking of the `auto_prepend_file` directive and your `foreach` option but, I think, `extract()` trumps `foreach` in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case it may be helpful, this is the code suggested on php.net to emulate **register_globals On**:

```
<?php
// Emulate register_globals on
if (!ini_get('register_globals')) {
    $superglobals = array($_SERVER, $_ENV,
        $_FILES, $_COOKIE, $_POST, $_GET);
    if (isset($_SESSION)) {
        array_unshift($superglobals, $_SESSION);
    }
    foreach ($superglobals as $superglobal) {
        extract($superglobal, EXTR_SKIP);
    }
}
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.misc.php#faq.misc.registerglobals

Answer (score 5):

From the [PHP manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), it says that:

> **This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.**

However, a Google search revealed this method on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973028):

> Nope, it's finally gone for good. Whatever site is still using globals
>   had, what, half-a-dozen years or more now to fix the code?
>
> The quickest solution is to create the globals from scratch by running
>   this code at the beginning of the app:
>
> Code:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$val) {
    ${$key}=$val;
}
```

> You have to be careful that any variable created this way isn't already defined in the remainder of the script.
>
> You can force this code to be run ahead of every page on the site by
>   using the auto_prepend_file directive in an .htaccess file.

**I'd strongly recommend looking at the code that requires `register_globals` and changing it so that it works properly with it being disabled.**

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini before:

```
auto_globals_jit = On
```

After:

```
auto_globals_jit = Off
```