# Unregistering Globals?

Tags: php, session, foreach, superglobals

I'm having trouble understading this function. I know what register_globals is and how long it has been depreciated from PHP but I'm looking at this code and I'm like, what in the?...

```
<?php
    //Undo register_globals
    function unregister_globals() {
        if (ini_get(register_globals)) {
            $array = array('_REQUEST', '_SESSION', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES');
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
                    if ($var === $GLOBALS[$key]) {
                        unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The part in which I'm not understanding is this...

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
        if ($var === $GLOBALS[$key]) {
            unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
         }
     }
 }
```

This foreach loop is cycling through each value in $array we defined then the inner foreach loop is grabbing a super global array from GLOBALS whether it is _REQUEST, _SESSION, _SERVER, _ENV, _FILES, etc... Afterwords it seems like the condional is checking to see if $var is equal to a GLOBAL variable or what not. If so then we'll unset it.

But I'm still having a major difficulty wrapping my head around this one...

**UPDATE**
Here is the snippet of code I'm experimenting with and debugging. What happens if register_globals is on, and a hacker comes barreling along, inserts ?auth=1 into the query string? Will auth be deleted from GLOBALS or will it be echoed out?

```
if( true ) {
    $globals = array(
        '_COOKIE',
        '_GET',
        '_POST',
        '_REQUEST',
        '_SERVE',
        '_SESSION'
    );

    foreach($globals as $global) {
        foreach($GLOBALS[$global] as $k => $v) {
            /* $GLOBALS['_GET'] on the first loop; */
            /* IF WE SAY, $GLOBALS['app_dir'], WE GET THE VALUE */

            if( $v == $GLOBALS[$k] ) {
                echo "K=> " . $k . "<br />";
                echo "V => " . $v . "<br />";
                echo "GLOB => " . $GLOBALS[$k] . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }

            echo $authorized; // a intentional non-defined variable

    //print_r($GLOBALS);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: it unsets ALL the globals, its crazy, dont do it

Comment: I checked my GLOBALS array and all variables were still there after running this inside my code.

Comment: @W3Geek var_dump($_GLOBALS) before you run this, and see what does it contain

Comment: You can't alter an array inside a foreach loop unless you pass the iterator by reference. So it looks like this is *supposed to* delete all globals, but it wouldn't work unless you did `foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => &$var)`

Comment: @user4035 I see all my global information? Should I var_dump afterwards?

Comment: @EmmyS Interesting, why does my code remove all the values from $data array?

Comment: @W3Geek So, this code doesn't modify $_GLOBALS array at all?

Comment: @user4035 - I don't know. Per the [docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), "In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &."

Comment: @user4035 Yup unsets and $data becomes array(0); Hmm?

Comment: @EmmyS I think, I found the reason. In the does, they use: `foreach ($arr as &$value)` - no key. While we are unsetting, using key. That's why it works.

Comment: @user4035 Results of var_dump: int(1) int(1) int(2) int(2) int(3) int(3) array(0) { }

Comment: @user4035 Sounds perfectly valid to me? Maybe because you are getting a reference since you have the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I was able to see how this actually works, I was able to wrap my head around it. Essentially if users are using PHP 5.3.0 or below and 'register_globals' is enabled, hackers can query common variables names such as 'authorized', 'username', etc to feed in there own values if the variable was already defined by the developer.

**Example:**

```
if( is_authorized() ) {
    $auth = 1;
}

if( $auth ) {
    // do authorization code here!!!
} else {
    show_login();
}
```

You can see $auth is condiotionally defined. If a hacker comes along and tries something like, index.php?auth=1 or index.php?auth=true then PHP will register that as a global value, it'll be checked in the conditional, and our hacker will have access to the application.

I found that...

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
        if ($var === $GLOBALS[$key]) {
            unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

... actually unsets these values and the hacker won't have access, however, there is also a bug as I previously thought. I have two globals in my framework called $app_dir and $sys_dir pointing to two important directories. If hackers come along and say something like index.php?app_dir=application&sys_dir=system then it'll actually unset those global variables from $GLOBALS. This calls for a potential danger inside of my framework for anyone using it on PHP 5.3.0 or below.

Basically how this works is the conditional checks to see if $var *(our value, 'system')* is equal to the same value as what's inside $GLOBAL['sys_dir']. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There is no need for this if: `if ($var === $GLOBALS[$key])`. This code is bad.

Comment: Let me try it without it. Wouldn't it unset everything then?

Comment: Yes, I have shown you in the beginning of my answer, that it's checking the same thing. And therefore is always true.

Comment: If you have 2 globals, pointing to important directories, they must be defined somewhere. When you set new values to them, hackers values will be lost. What's the danger?

Comment: @user4035 Wait it maybe needed! That bug I mentioned above is even worse if you remove the conditional check. Now somebody can query index.php?app_dir&sys_dir and it unsets them completely. Yes they are defined by me but this code will unset them if they are queried, posted, etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42737/discussion-between-w3geek-and-user4035)

Comment: No, sorry, too busy now. "if you remove the conditional check" - nothing will happen, because this condition is useless.

Comment: Also I don't think, that these variables will be dangerous in $_GET or $_REQUEST arrays. If you use them as global variables, values stored in those arrays won't be used.

Comment: Oh lol that's fine. I just saw the StackOverflow recommendation and clicked on it. :P But yes, it makes the bug I mentioned above worse because it'll unset no matter what value is queried. I tried it multiple times and it breaks my framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code looks weird:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
        if ($var === $GLOBALS[$key]) {//<- ?
            unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
         }
     }
```

You can imitate what's going in, using a simple array, and make sure, that this `if` is absolutely useless:

```
<?php
$data = array(1,2,3);

foreach ($data as $key => $var) {
    var_dump($var);
    var_dump($data[$key]);
    if ($var === $data[$key]) {
        unset($data[$key]);
    }
}
```

output:

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(2)
int(2)
int(3)
int(3)
```

As you can see, the values are equal every time, and in the end $data will be empty.

### Update

Here is the script, you can reproduce on your machine:

```
<?php
extract($_REQUEST);

var_dump($auth);
$array = array('_REQUEST', '_SESSION', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES');
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if(isset($GLOBALS[$value]))
    {
        foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
            unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($auth);
```

While calling it like this: `http://site/script.php?auth=1`

It gives the following output for me:

```
string(1) "1"
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: auth on line 14
NULL
```

So, it seems, that auth variable was destroyed. But $GLOBALS array still contains a lot of data.

### Update 2

I think, our error was here:

```
unset($GLOBALS[$key]);
```

Why are we unsetting the key of a foreign array. If you do it like this:

```
$array = array('_REQUEST', '_SESSION', '_SERVER', '_ENV', '_FILES');
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if(isset($GLOBALS[$value]))
    {
        foreach ($GLOBALS[$value] as $key => $var) {
            unset($GLOBALS[$value][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

It will empty $_REQUEST, $_SESSION and all the other necessary arrays.

Comment: Yes but say I have a variable $authorized I forgot to define somewhere. A hacker could just come strolling along and add ?auth=1 to give himself godmode. Would this unset $auth from GLOBALS or? This code is weird.

Comment: @W3Geek Trying to make an experiment now. Will let you know soon.

Comment: @W3Geek I think, I found the cause. Look at Update 2.

Comment: I'm gonna have to wait til I get home to try this out. I'm experimenting right now but have no way to turn register_globals on. It is disabled on my development server. I just want to make sure I understand this. It's so complicated and there aren't many resources on it?

Comment: @W3Geek register_globals is also off on my machine. I used extract($_REQUEST); to imitate register_globals on behaviour. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706098/enable-register-globals-in-php-5-4

Comment: Cool! :) I'll try that out. I made a update on my post above with what I'm trying to wrap my header around...

Comment: My results:

VAR_DUMP AUTH BEFORE string(9) "123456789"
VAR_DUMP AUTH BEFORE string(9) "123456789"

Comment: @W3Geek Yes, this code won't help you, if you want to remove all the unnecessary global values. To do it, you must define an array of all the valid global values names, and undefine all those, that are not inside this list.

Comment: @W3Geek Going to sleep now, will be back in 9 hours.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to experiment and gain a understanding of how this is working. I was expecting $auth to be NULL; I'll be back on later.

Answer (score 0):

Globals ( especially $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_ENV, ... and the $GLOBALS-Entries of this Superglobals ) are initially filled by PHP and should never be (over)written oder deleted by any application.

Any manipulation of Superglobal-Values drops the authenticity of the current request and works against the intentional behavior of PHP.

The nested foreach means that a given Array would be iterated ( outter foreach ) and each entry would be iterated too. The Array-Key is served as $key and the array-value as $var

Comment: Wouldn't you unset a GLOBAL per-say if a I queried ?auth=1 in the URL and already had a $auth variable in my code?

Comment: no, i wouldn't, existing variables doesn't impact $_GET-Values. Older PHP versions allows an security impacting behaviour called "register globals" which is deprecated since decades. With PHP 5.5.x it's only possible to overwrite existing variables while extract()'ing superglobals ( which equals to the old register globals behaviour and is definitily worst practice ).