# Why should we unregister globals in php?

Tags: php

I was following a course to build a framework using PHP.
I have a problem in understanding the unregister_globals function before create a controller instance

Here are the code

```
    private function _unregister_globals(){
        if(ini_get('register_globals')){
            $globalsAry = ['_SESSION', '_COOKIE', '_POST', '_GET','REQUEST','_SERVER','_ENV','_FILE'];
            foreach($globalsAry as $g){
                foreach($GLOBALS[$g] as $k => $v){
                    if($GLOBALS[$k] === $v){
                        unset($GLOBALS[$k]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is, why we need to unregister globals? what will happen if we do not?

Comment: ... because *register_globals* was a horrible, horrible mistake on the part of PHP and has now been removed. So, tbh, in any modern PHP application this function will be completely pointless as `ini_get('register_globals')` will **never** be truthy.

Comment: @CD001 this is really an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Cid - question looks like a duplicate anyway from the *Related* links to the side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432774/unregistering-globals - so it shouldn't really be answered in any greater detail I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unregistering Globals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432774/unregistering-globals)