# $_GET variables automatically parsed

Tags: php

I'm trying to fix a very old website (10+ years old) for a customer who had different websites made by the same developer at the time.
In the code of this website, the variables that are passed through "$_GET" are immediatly referenced, something like this:

```php
/* Code in the website */

if ($lng) {


/* What I would have expected */

$lng = isset($_GET["lng"]) ? $_GET["lng"] : "";

if ($lng) {
```

The code in the website stopped working after some updates, so I was wondering: how is it that it previously worked? Was there a php mod or was it a feature of php that has been deprecated?

I'm asking so that I can find a better way to solve this issue in other websites made with the same technology.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706098/how-can-i-emulate-register-globals-in-php-5-4-or-newer

Comment: The concept comes from `register_globals`, which is explained in more detail in the linked duplicate.  As a matter of (widely held) opinion, it's *good* that this no longer works in the given codebase.  It shouldn't have been used in the first place.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, didn't know about it! And I agree, it was not a good idea...